# tricks to tell whether an integral function is absolute convergent.

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

With measure theory I am experimenting with Tonelli's theorem and it is going just fine, but I always get stuck at proving absolute convergence of integrals.

Examples are:

1. $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} |e^{-xy}\sin(x)\sin(y)|\, dxdy$$
2. $$\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{1} \left|\frac{xy}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\right|\,dxdy$$

I think using substitutions can do the trick in 2) but I don't seem to see how to make one. Furthermore, I think estimations will help a lot.

Is there any literature or information on the web on how to look at these kind of problems?

Comment: @MarkFantini: your inequality goes in the wrong direction.

Comment: For the second integral, substitute $a =x^2$ and $b=y^2$. For an alternative idea, polar coordinates are frequently helpful.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks! Fixed: For the second use $2|xy| \leq x^2+y^2$ from the Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality.